# If cells from two spreadsheets are equal, clear a row in spreadsheet A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script so that if a student's name is one spreadsheet, then their data and their siblings data are removed from another spreadsheet.

More specifically, for each row, if a cell from spreadsheetA column A = any cell from spreadsheetB columns C, E, G, or I, clear the row in spreadsheetB from columns B to I.

We would greatly appreciate any help. This is what I have pieced together so far:

```js
function removeNotReturning() {

var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetA").getSheetByName("Not returning").getRange("A2:A10");
var ssAv = ss1.getValues();
var ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetB").getSheetByName("Master").getRange("B2:I10");
var ssBv = ss2.getValues();

for(var i = 0; i > ssA.getLastRow(); i++){
  if (ssAv[0][i] == ssBv[1][i]){
    var value = ssA.getRange(i+1, 1).getValue();
    ssB.getRange(i+1, 8).setValue("");
}}}
```

SpreadsheetA Example
[image]
SpreadsheetB Example
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Iterate through all rows in target range.
- For each row, retrieve the cells corresponding to `C`, `E`, `G`, `I`.
- Use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check whether any of these is included in the source range.
- If name is included, replace the row elements by empty strings. You can use [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) for that.

#### Code sample:

```
function removeNotReturning() {
  var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetA").getSheetByName("Not returning").getRange("A2:A10");
  var ssAv = ssA.getValues().flat();
  var ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetB").getSheetByName("Master").getRange("B2:I10");
  var ssBv = ssB.getValues();
  ssBv = ssBv.map(bRow => {
    var nameExists = [bRow[1],bRow[3],bRow[5],bRow[7]].some(bName => ssAv.includes(bName));
    if (nameExists) bRow.fill("");
    return bRow; 
  });
  ssB.setValues(ssBv);
}
```

Comment: Instead of emptying the row, If I needed to subtract 1 from the values for each row on columns [0],[2],[4],[6], what would that look like?

Comment: @Working4Us You could do that inside `map`. Consider posting a different question for this if you have doubts about how to exactly implement this.